# Orchard rendering custom shape, displaying one child only

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, content-type, shapes

I'm very new at orchard and I'm having troubles finding a solution for what I think is a basic problem.

I want to render my own custom shape 'Content-Button' for my custom content type 'Button'. This works wonderful!

The Button content is made out of:

- Display name
- Content picker

My custom shape looks like this:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
if (Model.Title != null) {
    Layout.Title = Model.Title;
}

Model.Classes.Add("content-item");

var contentTypeClassName = ((string)Model.ContentItem.ContentType).HtmlClassify();
Model.Classes.Add(contentTypeClassName);

var tag = Tag(Model, "div");
tag.AddCssClass("row");
}

@tag.StartElement
  <div id="" class="col-md-8 col-sm-10 col-xs-8 col-xs-push-2 col-sm-push-1 col-md-push-2 btn btn-secondary center-block">
    @Display(Model.Content)
</div>
@tag.EndElement
```

What I'm however trying to do is instead of calling '@Display(Model.Content)' I would like to call a specific shape to be rendered there. Like @Display(Model.Content.DisplayName).

I would like to do the same for the content picker so i can make a link in the div (through ID)

I've also tried to exlude certain (extra) fields using my theme's placement.info) but it seems I'm doing something wrong there as well.

```
<Match ContentType="Button">
    <Place Parts_Contents_Publish="-"></Place>
    <Place Fields_Common_Text="-"/>
</Match>
```

Note: The 'Fields_Common_Text' was purely a test but it stills renders that shape on my button.

If somebody could point me in the right direction, explain it or send me some very good documentation to read through I would be a very happy man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access fields directly as following:

```
@Model.ContentItem.ButtonPart.DisplayName.Value
```

and same thing for content picker field, then you don't need to use placement.info file any more.

Comment: Thanks! This will certainly help me later. At the moment I've 'solved' it with entering pure HTML on the page.